# How to Get All Resource Group name it's details in all subscription, how to vm details(created date, who created ,vmname.) using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-4.0

How to Get All Resource Group name it's details in all subscription
How to get vm details(created date, who created ,vmname, which storage account created) using PowerShell

I need PowerShell script

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, what have you tried, what didnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try below power shell script:

To achieve that you just need to use [Get-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Resources/Get-azRoleAssignment?view=azps-2.0.0) together with a filter:

```
Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentOperation -DeploymentName test -ResourceGroupName test
```

Or You could also try below one:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object { $_.Scope -match 'resource_group_name' }
```

For more details you could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-2.0.0)